# Store.Builders.HydratedFourRowTemplate is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vb.net

i have an issue regarding to WAPI.sendButtons to open chat in whatsApp Api

im getting this error

```
Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HydratedFourRowTemplate')
```

[image: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HydratedFourRowTemplate')]

thanks.

Comment: You are spamming tags.